# not a class or namespace

Tags: c++

My C++ is little rusty. Can anyone see why I am seeing "not a class or namespace" compile-time error in main() while accessing i.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Singleton2 {
    Singleton2(){
        i = 0;
    }
public:
    int i;

    friend Singleton2 & singleton2();
};

Singleton2 & singleton2(){
    static Singleton2 ms;

    return ms;
}

int main() {
    Singleton2 ms = singleton2();
    int i = ms::i;              // error: `ms' is not a class or namespace
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use dot `.` operator to access non-static members, not the scope resolution operator `::`

```
int i = ms.i;
```

Note that the assignment below

```
Singleton2 ms = singleton2();
```

makes a *copy* of your singleton. Your `singleton2()` returns a reference, so you should probably make `ms` a reference as well:

```
Singleton2 &ms = singleton2();
```